# Handling callbacks when doing async programming and dealing with scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, controller, async.js

I'm using HapiJS to create a little backend for my side-project. In grabbing RSS feeds, I want to loop through my list of website URLs, grab the correct RSS links in the `<head>`, then loop through the RSS feeds, pulling out the articles, to return an aggregated JSON response (via the `reply()` call in HapiJS), to have all these sites articles in one response for my API.

I'm fumbling with a couple of things:

1. The async nature of Node/JavaScript and doing what I want here in the most efficient/canonical manner
2. And getting my data within the innermost loop to the outer one to return (scope).

This code `console.log`s all the article data correctly, but I'm unsure how to properly place the callback() to get these arrays of articles from each site, into one larger array that I will eventually return. This is the one controller in my HapiJS backend that is handling this (suggestions on how to break this up better welcome as well).

```
var feed = require('feed-read');
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('lodash');
var finder  = require('find-rss');
var async = require('async');

module.exports = blogs;

function blogs () {
  var articles;
}

blogs.getAll = function (req, reply) {
  //TODO: Handle facebook tech blog which probably requires an accept header properly set
  //TODO: Store all proper web/rss feeds somewhere
  //TODO: periodically loop through them and get new articles, and store them
  //TODO: Clean up API instead of one monolithic endpoint

    //iterate over all sites
    var sites = [
      'http://eng.joingrouper.com',
      'http://eng.rightscale.com',
      'https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog',
      'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/',
      'http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/',
      'http://yahooeng.tumblr.com/',
      'http://code.flickr.net/',
      'http://engineering.pinterest.com/',
      'https://blog.twitter.com/engineering',
      'http://blog.42floors.com/',
      'http://engineering.flipboard.com/',
      'http://codeascraft.com/',
      'http://engineering.foursquare.com/',
      'http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/',
      'https://code.facebook.com/posts/',
      'https://labs.spotify.com/',
      'http://engineering.voxer.com/',
      'http://www.ebaytechblog.com/',
      'http://tech.gilt.com/',
      'http://engineering.heroku.com/',
      'http://www.thumbtack.com/engineering/',
      'http://engineering.silk.co/',
      'https://www.paypal-engineering.com/',
      'http://code.zynga.com/',
      'http://blog.risingstack.com/',
      'https://tech.blog.box.com/',
      'https://engineering.groupon.com/',
      'http://dev.hubspot.com/blog',
      'http://code.hootsuite.com/',
      'http://www.buzzfeed.com/techblog',
      'https://medium.com/medium-eng',
      'http://code.mixpanel.com'
    ];
    var feeds = [];
    var articles = [];
    var href;

    //var results = blogs.getAllFeeds(sites, articles);
    // 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
    async.each(sites,
      // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
      function(site, callback){
        // Call an asynchronous function, often a save() to DB
          console.log('start first site..');
          // Async call is done, alert via callback
              //Discover feed
              finder(site, function(error, response, body){
                if (error) {
                  return error;
                }
                  if(response[0]){
                    href = response[0]['href'];
                  }
                  //TODO: handle these conditions better
                  if(href === '/atom.xml' ||
                     href === '/rss/' ||
                     href === '/feed.xml'){
                       //Make full urls out of those sites that reference their feed relatively
                       href = site + href;
                  }
                  //Parse feed for articles
                  feed(href, function(err, articles) {
                     if (err) {
                         console.log("SITE: "  + site);
                         console.log("Error: " + err);
                         console.log("---------------------------------------------");
                     } else {
                      var _articles = [];
                      _.forEach(articles, function(article) {
                        //console.log(article['title']);
                        _articles.push(article['title'], article['link']);
                      });
                      console.log(_articles);
                     }
                  });
        });
        blogs.checkDone(sites);
      },
      // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
      function(err, _articles, articles){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('done');
        reply('ap');
        // All tasks are done now
        //checkDone(sites);
      }
    );
    if(!articles){
      reply(articles);
    }
};

blogs.checkDone = function(object) {
  _.after(object.length, function(){
      console.log('done here');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've done a rather in depth review of your code which I'll post below. It's fully commented so it should hopefully make sense. I haven't tested it but I should not have changed any functionality.

There were a few things I had to make assumptions for because of missing information. For example, what happens if the `response[0].href` (in my code, `first`) is **not** `/rss/`, `/feed.xml` or `/atom.xml`? In my code, I made it such that in these cases an empty array is passed - In the end result this array is flattened so it doesn't show.

The main thing I noticed is that you don't quite grasp callbacks and limitation of scope just yet. For example you have a `href` variable exposed to the entire of `getAll` when really that variable only needs to exist when you call `feed` inside of a nested scope.

In addition, you do this strange thing where you call `blogs.checkDone(sites)` inside of a function that can only be called *whilst we are checking sites* - and you don't really do anything except log it, when you could really avoid the `blogs.checkDone(sites)` function altogther by listening to the callback of `getAll`. With that in mind, here is the revised code I put together for you. It is about 20 lines shorter (if you factor in the urls I removed), doesn't have nearly as much code duplication and hopefully makes more sense to you than your original code would make if you looked at it in 6 months time.

The main thing i changed was that I changed `async.each` to `async.map`; `async.each` is only really for executing a function multiple times in a row and discarding the result. This fine but in your case you end up having to create scope variables that aren't necessary. Instead, `async.each` allows the receiver of the callback from your function to simply catch the results as their second parameter.

```
var url = require('url')
  , _ = require('lodash')
  , feed = require('feed-read')
  , async = require('async')
  , finder = require('find-rss');

// First move the site array outside of the blog function, 
// we should pass this into the module.
var sites = [
  'http://eng.joingrouper.com',
  'http://eng.rightscale.com',
  'https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog',
  ....
];

// Blog.js
// NB You may want to turn this into a newable type rather than
// using functional notation
function Blog(sites) {
  // Your get all function.
  // I have removed your 'req' argument as it is not used, and I have
  // changed 'reply' to 'done' for semantics.
  // done will be invoked when getAll is completed.
  // done should have the signature (error, results)
  getAll = function() {
    // Use map, not each - each is simply for performing a function x times.
    // map is used when you expect a value; it's callback then allows you
    // to catch a result as well as an error
    async.map(sites, 
      function(site, callback) {
        finder(site, function(error, feeds, body) {
          // If error is an error, then invoke the callback
          // with the error. this is propogated to async's 3rd argument.
          if(_.isError(error)) return callback(error);
          // What happens if response[0] is null/undefined? Your code will break.
          // As this is a collection result I'll reply with an empty array.
          if(_.isEmpty(feeds)) return callback(null, []]);
          // What happens if href is not /atom.xml or /rss/ or /feed.xml?
          var first = _(_.first(feeds).href);
          if(!first.includes('/atom.xml') || !first.includes('/rss/') || !first.includes('/feed.xml'))
            return callback(null, []);
          var fullUrl = url.resolve(site, first);
          feed(fullUrl, function(error, articles) {
            if(_.isError(error)) return callback(error);
            // No need to push to intermediate array.. we can just map the array.
            var results = _.map(articles, function(article) {
              // In your original code, you did .push(title,link).
              // This would push title and link to separate elements.
              // I assume you meant to push title and link to a single object.
              return { title: article.title, link: article.link };
            });
            // Invoke callback with the completed results
            callback(null, results);
          });
        });
      },
      function(err, results) {
        // Flatten nested arrays to single dimensional array
        done(err, _.flatten(results));
      });
  };

  // No need for a 'check done' function, and that does not make sense
  // anyway.

  return {
    getAll: getAll
  };
}
module.exports = Blog;
```

The usage now looks a bit like this:

```
var blog = require('./blog');
blog(['http://code.mixpanel.com', ....]).getAll(function(error, results) {
  if(_.isError(error)) throw error;
  // do something with results
});
```

If you have any further questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Perfect. This got me up and running. Couple of things: (1) I had to add require('url') for your 'url.resolve' usage (2) I had to add (req,reply) back to the siqnature, and change 'done' back to 'reply', because that's what HapiJS expects. Then all was right.

To answer some of your other Q's: (1) Yes, async.map is what I wanted, I didn't understand how .each worked. (2) 'What happens if response[0] is null/undefined?' Yup, I'll handle this better, as well as timeouts.

Comment: (3) The intention of the inflexible '/atom.xml' checking is a matter of handling relative urls in the head of the HTML page for their RSS feeds. Some are full urls, some are relative. So I think I'll change it to something that says 'is full url' if not, then concatenate the '/whatevs' with 'http://example.com'. I'll have to look if the url lib in Nodejs can do this easily. I don't think url.resolve will do what I want. (4) Yes I wanted to push title, url as single object, thank you!

Comment: Additional Q's: `// NB You may want to turn this into a newable type rather than
// using functional notation` Can you explain why newable vs func, and when you'd want one over the other?

Comment: Additional Q's: I obviously haven't quite wrapped my head around plain callbacks in JS yet. (I've used promises before to get around them.) When doing callbacks, how do you know what to pass? `callback(null, results);` What's null here for? Any solid, callback JS tutorials you know about you could point me to?

Comment: Additional Q's: Using lodash, what's the best way to sort the flattened array by published? `{ title: 'Internship stories',
    link: 'https://code.mixpanel.com/2011/11/15/internship-stories/',
    published: Tue Nov 15 2011 18:54:15 GMT-0500 (EST),
    author: 'Suhail Doshi',
    site: 'https://code.mixpanel.com' },
  { title: 'Why We Moved Off The Cloud',
    link: 'https://code.mixpanel.com/2011/10/27/why-we-moved-off-the-cloud/',
    published: Thu Oct 27 2011 19:36:08 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    author: 'mxpnl',
    site: 'https://code.mixpanel.com' },` `_.sortBy()` ?

Comment: I can answer your questions, let us [take this to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21957/chat-for-dan-and-program247365)